# Get function from string containing the full name

Tags: python, eval, python-importlib

I have a string like:

```
str = "pwd.getpwuid(1000)"
```

Now, if I try to eval() that it may raise an exception because I have not import pwd yet (or maybe not if I have).

So I decided to write a parser that: splits that string on "." and get a list:

```
lis = ["pwd", "getpwuid(1000)"]
```

then take `lis[0]`, if it does not contain `"("` or `")"` I call

```
importlib.import_module(lis[0])
```

and then again the eval.

Can I make the same thing better?

Comment: Fairly good, although why do you find yourself in such a situation in the first place?

Comment: It is a little complicated but I can't do different!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jonrsharpe, However the OP is looking for an alternative method to his code, which I guess should be acceptable.

Comment: What if the prefix before the function is some object? Or if it’s some object in another module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I must change the strings to contains body of functions:

```
str = "(lambda x: __import__('pwd').getpwuid(x))(1000)"
```

eval() on this is ok!

(lambda or def obviously are the same)

Answer (score 0):

how about splitting the positionnal args of the function in lis[2] and the named args in lis[3] with some regex and doing

```
lib = importlib.import_module(lis[0])
lib.__dict__[lis[1]](*list[2],**list[3])
```

Comment: this takes for granted that lis[1] is only the name of the function, not its args